# I have made one post on WordPress http://www.rigelnetworks.com/service-menu/ wherein I created menu tab

Tags: wordpress

I have made one post on WordPress http://www.rigelnetworks.com/service-menu/ wherein I created menu tab but the problem is that above url is crawled in Google (site:rigelnetworks.com) and it doesn't have proper format. I don't know what to do? please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Google or other search engines to crawl a page, add:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

to your header. If you only want that tag to be on one page, you could use something like the following in your header file:

```
<?php if( is_page( 'service-menu' ) ) : ?>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then, it will put the no-index, no-follow tag on just that page. If you want it site wide, there is an option in WP admin area under Settings > Reading Settings > Discourage Search Engines From Indexing This Site -- check that off for a sitewide solution.

Comment: ok , but all services pages listed under this url. Will other pages effect if I block this url?

Comment: Well, you have a menu at the top which appears to already link to these pages so in as far as this page is not the only place that links to them, not so much. If you want search engines to NOT index the page, but to follow all the links on the page, change the meta to <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW"> or you could just leave FOLLOW off since the default is to follow and index, you generally don't need to specify them. You said "the problem is the url is being crawled by Google" so this would solve that. Beyond that, I don't know the function and reason for this page.

Comment: In your document header somewhere before </head>.